# Problem on partially coloring the content of a cell in excel based on condition

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to Python Programming and struggling with below problem
 I have a requirement where to one of the cell of excel we are writing as "PASS - Test1 | PASS - Test2 | FAIL - Test3"
 However after that I am supposed to format the cell with 
 'PASS - Test1' as Green color font
 'PASS - Test2' as Green color font
 'FAIL - Test3' as  Red color font 
 the "|" stay as default font color
 I am not able to figure out a right approach towards it.